# Using route.snapshot with routerLink in angular app to get url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url, routerlink

I am trying to handle a situation in my Angular app where I have some interior links (links within a section - that use a different navigation mechanism than the rest of the app) that are being loaded via routerLink. That works well enough by itself, and looked like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/section-start'" routerLinkActive="selected">Section Start</a>
```

However, since I first set those links up, we now have some filter selections that we are saving in the url as well. So I am trying to figure out how to pass those here as well. I'm thinking Angular's `route.snapshot` could work here. So I am trying this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/section-start', getParams()]" routerLinkActive="selected">Section Start</a>
```

And `getParams()` looks like this:

```
getParams() {
    return this.route.snapshot;
}
```

This gets me closer... However, I still end up a doubling-up of the main url link (not surprising since it's taking a snapshot of the entire url link), and, say if I have a "Spanish" language filter enabled, the url in the address bar ends up looking like this:

http://somesite.com/section-start;url=section-start%3Bpn_lang_e%3Dtrue%3Bpn_lang_s%3DSpanish;

Whereas using my usual routing mechanism from other areas of the site, the same params would result in a url like this (and this is what it SHOULD look like):

http://somesite.com/section-start;pn_lang_e=true;pn_lang_s=Spanish

Since I am getting close to the correct url by passing in `getParams()`, I assume there's a way I can clean this up/parse it differently to end up with the correct url string. Any ideas as to how I can do this - or is there a better approach that's different than this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this is a parameter serialization issue.

Comment: It looks like it's escaping a certain characters in the URL. Those character shouldn't even be in the URL in the first place but are coming from the object returned by `getParams`